# Asynchronously writing a spawned process' stdout+stderr to a file in a thread-safe way in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I have a fairly standard setup:

```
    void Run()
    {
        this.sw = File.CreateText(logfile)

        start.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process proc = Process.Start(start)
        proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        ...
    }

    private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
        }
    }
```

It all works great, I thought, until I did my first trial run and after a couple of minutes perfect running it crashed:

> Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception:
>   System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Proba ble I/O race condition detected
>   while copying memory. The I/O package is not thr ead safe by default.
>   In multithreaded applications, a stream must be accessed in  a
>   thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by
>   TextReader's or Te xtWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies
>   to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader.    at
>   System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffset, Array dst,
>   Int 32 dstOffset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count) 
>   at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value)

I'm only running a single thread in my app so the only way I can think this happened is if stdout & stderror both fire events at the same time.

What should my code look like to implement the "thread-safe wrappers" mentioned?

Comment: You should probably edit your question and make a short but complete program so less advanced users can understand the problem if they're facing it too.

Comment: Wow, awesome exception message.

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you have a WriteLine put a lock around it such as

```
public class MyClass
{
   object myLockObject = new object();

   public void MyOperationCalledOnAnEvent(string data)
   {
      lock (myLockObject)
          sw.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
private readonly object _looker = new object();

private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            lock(_locker)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Another solution can be adding outputs to, for instance, `ConcurrentQueue`, then retrieve messages in separate thread and save to stream.